# What sends a PUT via ajax to a Spring controller

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

I want to send an email using ajax and PUT method to the controller. Well, I noticed that data is not being sent as a 'query parameter', but as 'form data'(https://zapodaj.net/f1b8ed0b2a16b.png.html). By what I can not use RequestParam. I need to apply RequestBody (I think).
I created this dto

```
    public class ChangeEmailDTO {
         @Getter @Setter private String email;
    }
```

And the controller I modified in this way

```
@PutMapping("/changeEmail")
public boolean changeEmail(
        @ReuqestBody ChangeEmailDTO changeEmailDTO
) {
    System.out.println("email: " + changeEmailDTO.getEmail());

    return true;
}
```

And shipping

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/changeEmail',
        data: {
            email: $('#email').val()
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('function');
        }
    });
```

However, it does not work. I have no idea how to fix this. Maybe I need to use another annotation? The controller indicates there is no such address.

Comment: Do you need to use put or can you control what happens inside the controller and just use post?

Comment: If I use POST, it works fine.